# Show that sum of $r^k$ is a polynomial of order $k+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

> Using proof by induction on $k$, show $P(k)$ holds $\forall\, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
>   $$ P(k): \;\;\;\;\sum_{r=1}^n r^k = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} + E_k(n)$$
>   where $E_k(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$ or less.

A previous part of the question asked for proof that
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+k-1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k)}{k+1}$$
which I can manage. Note that the coefficient of $n^{k+1}$ is $\frac{1}{k+1}$ and the rest is a polynomial $E_k(n)$.

I can verify $P(1)$ but I cannot manage the $P(x) \implies P(x+1)$ stage. All I can manage is an upper bound.

Note that $r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+k) > r\times (r+1-1)\times (r+2-2)\times \cdots \times (r+k-k) = r^{k+1}$. Thus,
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^{k+1} < \sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+k)$$
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^{k+1} < \frac{n^{k+2}}{k+2}+E_{k+1}(n)$$
However, I need to prove that the coefficient of $n^{k+2}$ is exactly $\frac{1}{k+2}$, not just less than the above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume that $P(1),\ldots,P(k-1)$ are true and prove $P(k)$.

Note that $$\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+k-1)=\sum_{r=1}^nr^k+\sum_{r=1}^nQ_{k-1}(r),$$
where $Q_{k-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k-1$. By induction hypothesis, $\sum_{r=1}^nQ_{k-1}(r)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k$. You can now show that $\sum_{r=1}^nr^k$ has the desired form.